# How to send only part of the information, not whole dataTable?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm writing a code that gets some data from DB, and renders it to user with the ability to change a record. There is no problem with small amount of data, but when it comes to big ones, server errors : parameter count exceeded allowed maximum 512. The Network section in developers instruments shows me that my code always sends all records by POST request, therefore i think I get this error. I wonder how to fix it? Thanks

I thought that code sends all data to server because its in free edit mode (I mean disabled="false"). I tried to disable it - not working.

```
<rich:dataTable styleClass="theme5" value="#{documentRules.getRules()}" var="d" rowKeyVar="r">
    <rich:column width="20" style="text-align:center;" id="code_#{counter.next()}">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.document.code']}</f:facet>
        <!--<h:panelGroup id="code2_#{d['id']}">-->
            <h:inputText id="code_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['code']}" disabled="true" style="text-align: center; width: 85px"/>
        <!--</h:panelGroup>-->

    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="25" style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.type']}</f:facet>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="docType_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['docType']}" required="true" style="max-width: 460px;" styleClass="input" disabled="true">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['ORIGINAL']}" itemValue="ORIGINAL"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['COPY']}" itemValue="COPY"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['NOTARIZED_COPY']}" itemValue="NOTARIZED_COPY"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['DUBLICATE']}" itemValue="DUBLICATE"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['ARCHIEVE']}" itemValue="ARCHIEVE"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['ELECTRONIC']}" itemValue="ELECTRONIC"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="15" style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.quantity']}</f:facet>
        <div style="width: 15px;">
        <h:inputText id="quantity_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['quantity']}" disabled="true" style="text-align: center; width: 40px" />
        </div>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.isReturned']}</f:facet>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="returned_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['returned']}" required="true" style="max-width: 460px;" styleClass="input" disabled="true">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['service.rules.returned.yes']}" itemValue="true"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['service.rules.returned.not']}" itemValue="false"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.group']}</f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="group_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['group']}" disabled="true" style="text-align: center"/>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['service.rules.unisodParams']}</f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="unisodParams_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['unisodparams']}" disabled="true" style="text-align: center" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column style="text-align:center;">
        <f:facet name="header">#{messages['Источник']}</f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="source_#{d['id']}" value="#{d['source']}" disabled="true" style="text-align: center" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="21">
        <div style="width: 21px;">
            <a:commandLink id="saveRule" type="submit" action="#{documentRules.saveDocument(d)}" process="code,docType,quantity,returned,group,unisodParams,source" reRender="editConditionPanel,serviceDocumentsPanel" oncomplete="showMessages()" ajaxSingle="true" ignoreDupResponses="true" eventsQueue="globalQueue" requestDelay="200" status="globalStatus">
                <span class="icon icon-point"/>
            </a:commandLink>
        </div>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="21">
        <div style="width: 21px;">
            <a:commandLink action="#{documentRules.editDocument(d)}" reRender="editConditionPanel,serviceDocumentsPanel" oncomplete="showMessages()" ajaxSingle="true" ignoreDupResponses="true" eventsQueue="globalQueue" requestDelay="200" status="globalStatus">
                <span class="icon icon-edit-contact"/>
            </a:commandLink>
        </div>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="21">
        <div style="width: 21px;">
            <a:commandLink action="#{documentRules.deleteDocument(d)}" reRender="editConditionPanel,serviceDocumentsPanel" oncomplete="showMessages()" ajaxSingle="true" ignoreDupResponses="true" eventsQueue="globalQueue" requestDelay="200" status="globalStatus">
                <span class="icon icon-delete-contact"/>
            </a:commandLink>
        </div>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

getRules its a method that takes data from DB by some criteria.

I expect from server not to send all the data at once. Only those, which were modified.

Answer (score 0):

you Should use pagination for this scenario.

Comment: It wont solve the problem right? It would only send small amounts of data on each page

Comment: Why not As you said 512 is the max limit to server so instead of sending all data if you send less data then it might be solve your issue.